# Estimate run time of Cirq circuit on forthcoming Google quantum computer

Tags: cirq

Calling cirq.Simulator().run(..) on your circuit to get an idea of how  it'd behave if you were to run on Google's (apparently) forthcoming real hardware is fine and dandy.  Is there a way to estimate how long it would take?

Apologies if this is not a suitable question for QC.SE or I've missed something obvious!

Answer (score 4):

You can get a rough idea of runtimes by using the `cirq.estimate_run_time` ([doc](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq_google/engine/estimate_run_time)), `cirq.estimate_run_sweep_time`([doc](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq_google/engine/estimate_run_sweep_time)), or `cirq.estimate_run_batch_time` ([doc](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq_google/engine/estimate_run_batch_time)).  These represent the different ways of running the quantum circuit (as a single program, a program plus a set of parameters for the program, or as a batch of programs plus parameters).